# Searching in component of specific content-type

Tags: strapi

I'm not sure how to proceed in this case:

I have a model **response**. This model has a reference to a repeated component **message** with a field **text**.

When i use the search in the top left of the **response** list i want to recieve results of all items where the **searchtext** ist included in the **text** field of the component inside the **response**.

Is this even possible? As far as i see the strapi.entityService.search only can search existing model-content and not component-content?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the relation type that is used for component, it's not possible to filter on this kind of field for the moment.

And there is no workaround for that. Sadly.